# Replacing Particular Numbers in Dataframe in R with character strings

Tags: r, dataframe

I am in need of replacing particular values in a numeric vector in R. I have a data frame like the following.

```
X1 = 1:20   
X2 = c(letters[1:20])   
df = data.frame(X1, X2) 
df <- df[sample(nrow(df)),]
df
   X1 X2
1  2  b
2  18 r
3  16 p
4  7  g
5  3  c
6  1  a
7  14 n
8  10 j
9  8  h
10 11 k
11 17 q
12 6  f
13 15 o
14 13 m
15 19 s
16 5  e
17 4  d
18 9  i
19 12 l
20 20 t
```

In this particular data frame I need all of the particular numeric values in X1 with character strings such that 1:5 = c("w"), 6:10 = c("x"), 11:15 = c("y"), and 16:20 = c("z").  So that the data frame above would look as follows:

```
   X1 X2
1  w  b
2  z  r
3  z  p
4  x  g
5  w  c
6  w  a
7  y  n
8  x  j
9  x  h
10 y  k
11 z  q
12 x  f
13 y  o
14 y  m
15 z  s
16 w  e
17 w  d
18 x  i
19 y  l
20 z  t
```

Thank you!

Comment: Please let others know if you are changing the expected output again.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `findInterval`

```
df$X1 <-  with(df, findInterval(X1, c(1, 6, 11, 16)))
df$X1
#[1] 1 4 4 2 1 1 3 2 2 3 4 2 3 3 4 1 1 2 3 4
```

NOTE: This returns the expected output showed in the OP's post.

Based on the new output

```
v1 <- setNames(1:4, c("w", "x", "y", "z"))
df$X1 <- names(v1[with(df, findInterval(X1, c(1, 6, 11, 16)))])
df$X1
#[1] "w" "z" "z" "x" "w" "w" "y" "x" "x" "y" "z" "x" "y" "y" "z" "w" "w" "x" "y" "z"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a new solution for the new desired output making use of the `chartr` function for character translation:

```
(from <- paste(letters[1:20], collapse = ""))
# [1] "abcdefghijklmnopqrst"
(to <- paste(rep(c("w", "x", "y", "z"), each = 5), collapse = ""))
# [1] "wwwwwxxxxxyyyyyzzzzz"

# chartr will translate the characters in its first argument
# to the corresponding characters in its second argument
# when it finds instances of those characters in its third argument
df$X1 <- chartr(from, to, df$X2)
#[1] "w" "z" "z" "x" "w" "w" "y" "x" "x" "y" "z" "x" "y" "y" "z" "w" "w" "x" "y" "z"
```

Another solution would be a lookup table using a named vector:

```
to <- rep(c("w", "x", "y", "z"), each = 5)
names(to) <- paste(letters[1:20])
to 
# a   b   c   d   e   f   g   h   i   j   k   l   m   n   o   p   q   r   s   t 
#"w" "w" "w" "w" "w" "x" "x" "x" "x" "x" "y" "y" "y" "y" "y" "z" "z" "z" "z" "z"

df$X1 <- to[df$X2]
#[1] "w" "z" "z" "x" "w" "w" "y" "x" "x" "y" "z" "x" "y" "y" "z" "w" "w" "x" "y" "z"
```